# Parsing key:value declarations

Tags: javascript

I recently ran into some issues with a plugin and outlined the issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34166423/with-operator-dashes-in-object-keys) and wanted to know if the modifications I've made below cover the scenarios that the `with` scope blocks would have covered.

I've modified some code to remove the `with` operator and I'm wondering if I've replicated everything properly in doing so.

```
var test = new Function('$f','$c','with($f){with($c){return{'+ declarations +'}}}'));
```

Where `$f` and `$c` are passed objects (From what I could tell, `$f` shouldn't ever have a property of `$c`). The `declarations` variable is a string that has a colon in it (EX: "value:color") and available within the scope.

Here is my modified code:

```
var test = function($f, $c, declarations) {
        var result = {};
        var value = "";
        var split = declarations.split(":");
        if (split.length < 2) {
          throw new Error("Declaration is in an invalid format");
        }
        if ($f[$c] !== undefined && $f[$c][split[1]]) {
          value = $f[$c][split[1]];
        }
        else if ($c[split[1]]) {
          value =  $c[split[1]];
        }
        else if ($f[split[1]]) {
          value =  $f[split[1]];
        }
        else {
          value =  "" + split[1];
        }
        var key = split[0];
        result[key] = value;
        return result;
};
```

Everything appears to work as it did previously, but this modification now handles the use case where the `declarations` variable could have a dash in it (EX: "value:background-color").  Additionally the `declarations` variable is passed into the function, to ensure it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

Consider tightening up the long if statement using `||` which should be equivalent to your current logic.  I can't test this for you, but see if this works:

```
var test = function($f, $c, declarations) {
  var split = declarations.split(":"), key, value, cIsFProp;

  if (split.length < 2)
    throw new Error("Declaration is in an invalid format");

  cIsFProp = $f[$c] !== undefined && $f[$c][split[1]];

  value = cIsFProp ? $f[$c][split[1]] : null;
  value = value || $c[split[1]]) || $f[split[1]]) || "" + split[1];
  key = split[0];
  return {[key]: value};
};
```

Comment: OOH - Good call.  I felt bad moving from a very clever single line into a multi-line function.  I'll give this a shot today.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is really hard to read in a first look. `$c` ,`$f` aren't no much descriptive. avoid to use that names, if it is came from a dependency injection, or your framework use this nomenclature, try to replace with a string internally.

Also you are doing a lot of treatment of the split. I suggest use 2 variables instead of a split each time.

The code itself looks good, but will be better add more context to understand the kind of check

```
var test = function($f, $c, declarations) {
                    var $betterF = $f;
        var result = {};
        var value = "";
        var split = declarations.split(":");
        var key = split[0];
        var tmpValue = split[1];
        if (split.length < 2) {
          throw new Error("Declaration is in an invalid format");
        }

        if (!$f[$c] && $f[$c][tmpValue]) {
          value = $f[$c][tmpValue];
        } else if ($c[tmpValue]) {
          value =  $c[tmpValue];
        } else if ($f[tmpValue]) {
          value =  $f[tmpValue];
        } else {
          value =  "" + tmpValue;
        }

        result[key] = value;
        return result;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for looking everything over.  The original code is within a plugin, and the naming conventions chosen there are by the person who wrote the plugin and not myself.  As such, I've kept them named the same.  The split was previously being done through the type conversion in the function constructor.  It shouldn't need to be modified past splitting a string into a key-value pair.

Comment: The plugin in question is `Backbone.Epoxy`.  I've submitted an issue and pull request to their repository [here](https://github.com/gmac/backbone.epoxy/issues/130).